# collaborating using same spotify client secret?

Tags: api, spotify, collaboration

I want to collaborate with a few people on an application that were creating which relies on the spotify API. I registered the application with my spotify account. Does this mean that all the collaborators can use my client secret and ID? Or do each of them need to individually register the application with their spotify account and use their client id and secret when working on the application?

Answer (score 0):

First: I am not a lawyer.

You should take a look into the Spotify Developer Terms of Service you agreed while creating your developer account: https://developer.spotify.com/terms/

There is this section VI (Access to Spotify Platform):

> 1. Security Codes
>
>    - a. As described on our developer site, to access and use certain
>        tools provided by our Spotify Platform, you must link your Spotify
>        account to a developer account. You will be issued one or more unique
>        I.D.s, keys, passwords, security codes, or tokens (each a “Security
>        Code”) for accessing the Spotify Platform and managing your account.
>        You agree to provide Spotify with accurate, complete and updated
>        registration information.
>    - b. You may only access your account with the Security Codes
>        provided by Spotify and the appropriate Security Code must be embedded
>        in your SDA, including in all updates and revisions, in a secure
>        manner not accessible by third parties. If you are developing a
>        Streaming SDA, each call to the Spotify Platform must incorporate a
>        valid Security Code.
>    - c. You may not sell, transfer, sublicense or otherwise disclose
>        your account or Security Codes to any other party or use it for any
>        other purpose except in connection with your SDA.
>    - d. You are entirely responsible for maintaining the confidentiality
>        of your account and Security Codes. You agree to notify Spotify
>        immediately if you believe that your account or Security Codes have
>        been compromised and cooperate with Spotify in the investigation of
>        any compromised Security Codes. You are fully responsible for all
>        activities that occur using your account and Security Codes,
>        regardless of whether such activities are undertaken by you or a third
>        party.

Definition of SDA:

> Spotify Developer Application or SDA. “Spotify Developer Application”
>   or “SDA” means any application, website or service that accesses the
>   Spotify Service or Spotify Content through, or which incorporates, the
>   Spotify Platform. Please note that Widgets are not included in the
>   definition of an SDA.

I assume your collaborators are not classified as "third party". But let them register their own Spotify Developer Application for testing purposes, if you do not trust them since you are entirely responsible for what they could do with those keys.